# double labeled tikz with backgrounds

Tags: tikz-pgf

Removing double printed labels from tikz diagrams

[image]

I have a tikz diagram, in which the labels appear double printed. My impression is that this might be due to some of the pacakges/commands that i am using to make hyperlinks in the document.

Interestingly only some labels in the diagram are double printed, and this is the only tikz diagram that this happens on in the document (it is also the only one in which backgrounds is used - so that may be significant).

Can anyone find a way of removing the lower x(.;p,I) and the one of the E(s,p)s?

```
    % !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
%%
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=2cm]{geometry} %INCLUDE FOR THESIS

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[space]{cite}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}% ...at least 13.59pt
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc,arrows.meta,shapes,fit}
\usepackage[noprefix]{nomencl}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\makenomenclature

%pretty pictures
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,backgrounds}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}

%\pgfdeclarelayer{background}

%% START OF DOCUMENT %%
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header and footer
 % \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \leftmark}
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage\ }% Custom footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the header visible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}

% Redefine the plain page style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage\ } %
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the header invisible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}

\pagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{imagepage} \newcommand*{\foreachpage}[2]{%
     \begingroup
         \sbox0{\includegraphics{#1}}%
         \xdef\foreachpage@num{\the\pdflastximagepages}%
     \endgroup
\setcounter{imagepage}{0}%
     \@whilenum\value{imagepage}<\foreachpage@num\do{%
         \stepcounter{imagepage}%
         #2\relax }%
     }
\makeatother

%allow smaller pieces of text bellow figures
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.15}  % allow minimal text w. figs
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.84}   % allow minimal text w. figs
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.8}  % allow minimal text w. figs
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[loose/.style={inner sep=.7em}, oval/.style={ellipse,draw}] 
\newcommand{\p}{\mathbf{p}} \newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}} 
\node[minimum height=1.2ex,inner sep=0pt,circle,fill=black,label={$\p$}](p){};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[minimum height=13ex,circle,fill=black!11,fill
opacity=0.91,fit=(p),label={$E(\tilde{s},p)$}](pp){};
\end{scope}
%
\node[right=4 of p,minimum
height=13ex,circle,fill=black!11,label={$E(\underset{s}{\sim},\mathbf{p})$}](x1){$\x(\cdot;\p,\mathbf{I})$};
\node[right=5 of p,minimum height=1.2ex,inner sep=0pt,circle,fill=black,label={$\x(\cdot;\p,\mathbf{I})$}](x1){};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[minimum height=15ex,circle,fill=black!11,fill
opacity=0.91,fit=(x1),label={$E(\tilde{s},p)$}](xx1){};
\end{scope}
\node[right =5 of x1,minimum height=1.2ex,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=0ex,circle,fill=black,label={$y(\cdot;\p,\mathbf{I})$}](y){};
\def\ovalwidth{0.8}%Just used for the left one, adjust to make roughly match the others which are already wide 
\def\ovalheight{0.5}%excess height, all will get the same height.
\coordinate(ovaltop) at ($(pp.north)+(0,\ovalheight)$);
\coordinate(ovalbot) at ($(pp.south)-(0,\ovalheight)$); 
\node[oval,inner sep=2pt,fit={(ovaltop)($(p)+(\ovalwidth,0)$)($(p)-(\ovalwidth,0)$)(ovalbot)},label=$\Omega$]{};
\node[oval,inner sep=2pt,fit={(xx1)(x1|-ovaltop)(x1|-ovalbot)},label=$\mathscr{F}_\Pi (\mathbf{I})$]{};
\node[oval,inner sep=2pt,fit={(y)(y|-ovaltop)(y|-ovalbot)($(y)+(\ovalwidth,0)$)($(y)-(\ovalwidth,0)$)},label=$\mathscr{G}_\Sigma (\mathbf{I})$]{};
\draw[-Latex,shorten >=7pt] ($(p)!0.5!(pp.east)$) -- node [above,inner sep=2em]{$X_\Pi(\p,\mathbf{I})$} (x1.text|-x1); \draw[-Latex,shorten >=5pt] ($(x1)!0.5!(xx1.east)$) -- node [above,inner sep=2em]{$Y_\Sigma(\x(\cdot;\p,I))$} (y); 
\draw[dotted] (pp.north) --  (x1.text|-x1); 
\draw[dotted] (pp.south) --  (x1.text|-x1); 
\draw[dotted] (xx1.north) --  (y); 
\draw[dotted] (xx1.south) --  (y);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{?}
\end{figure}  



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: @Abijah Can you please go back to your previous questions and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These labels are explicitly added in your tikzpicture, just remove all `\node`s you don't want in your image:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning,calc,arrows.meta,shapes,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[loose/.style={inner sep=.7em}, oval/.style={ellipse,draw}] 
\newcommand{\p}{\mathbf{p}} \newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}} 
\node[minimum height=1.2ex,inner sep=0pt,circle,fill=black,label={$\p$}](p){};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[minimum height=13ex,circle,fill=black!11,fill
opacity=0.91,fit=(p),label={$E(\tilde{s},p)$}](pp){};
\end{scope}
%
%\node[right=4 of p,minimum height=13ex,circle,fill=black!11,label={$E(\underset{s}{\sim},\mathbf{p})$}](x1){$\x(\cdot;\p,\mathbf{I})$};
\node[right=5 of p,minimum height=1.2ex,inner sep=0pt,circle,fill=black,label={$\x(\cdot;\p,\mathbf{I})$}](x1){};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[minimum height=15ex,circle,fill=black!11,fill
opacity=0.91,fit=(x1),label={$E(\tilde{s},p)$}](xx1){};
\end{scope}
\node[right =5 of x1,minimum height=1.2ex,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=0ex,circle,fill=black,label={$y(\cdot;\p,\mathbf{I})$}](y){};
\def\ovalwidth{0.8}%Just used for the left one, adjust to make roughly match the others which are already wide 
\def\ovalheight{0.5}%excess height, all will get the same height.
\coordinate(ovaltop) at ($(pp.north)+(0,\ovalheight)$);
\coordinate(ovalbot) at ($(pp.south)-(0,\ovalheight)$); 
\node[oval,inner sep=2pt,fit={(ovaltop)($(p)+(\ovalwidth,0)$)($(p)-(\ovalwidth,0)$)(ovalbot)},label=$\Omega$]{};
\node[oval,inner sep=2pt,fit={(xx1)(x1|-ovaltop)(x1|-ovalbot)},label=$\mathscr{F}_\Pi (\mathbf{I})$]{};
\node[oval,inner sep=2pt,fit={(y)(y|-ovaltop)(y|-ovalbot)($(y)+(\ovalwidth,0)$)($(y)-(\ovalwidth,0)$)},label=$\mathscr{G}_\Sigma (\mathbf{I})$]{};
\draw[-Latex,shorten >=7pt] ($(p)!0.5!(pp.east)$) -- node [above,inner sep=2em]{$X_\Pi(\p,\mathbf{I})$} (x1.text|-x1); \draw[-Latex,shorten >=5pt] ($(x1)!0.5!(xx1.east)$) -- node [above,inner sep=2em]{$Y_\Sigma(\x(\cdot;\p,I))$} (y); 
\draw[dotted] (pp.north) --  (x1.text|-x1); 
\draw[dotted] (pp.south) --  (x1.text|-x1); 
\draw[dotted] (xx1.north) --  (y); 
\draw[dotted] (xx1.south) --  (y);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{that's odd?}
\end{figure}  



\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Off-topic: please only load the packages you actually need for your document and don't load the same package multiple times.

Comment: thanks, I'm new to tikz, and had some help with this - so didn't spot that when i was debugging it!

Comment: @Abijah If you encounter similar problems in the future, it helps to search the code for specific characters, e.g. I searched for `,p`, which returned only a couple of places and then narrowed down to the one which needs to be removed.